# Scrapy Response not showing any table data

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to scrape this [website](http://www.nepalstock.com/main/floorsheet/index/0/)  and I tried running scrapy shell in my cli and I can get xpath response up to `//table[@class='table my-table']` this xpath but after that I cannot get any data as the response is empty array `[]` I don't feel the contents is hidden inside JavaScript I have missed some techniques or is my approach wrong with scrapy?

Here is my overall code for reference

```
class MarketDataSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "nepse_floorsheet"

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'http://www.nepalstock.com/main/floorsheet/index/0/'
        yield Request(url, callback=self.parse)


    def parse(self, response):

        for tr in response.xpath("//table[@class='table my-table']"):

            print(tr.xpath("//tbody//tr[position()>2and position()<23]"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove tbody tag then it will generate ResultSet but the output is alwaya changed dynamically from the present static table data.

**Example:**

```
class MarketDataSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "nepse_floorsheet"

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'http://www.nepalstock.com/main/floorsheet/index/1/'
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse)


    def parse(self, response):

        for tr in response.xpath("//table[@class='table my-table']//tr[position()>2 and position()<23]"):
            yield {
                'Quantity':tr.xpath('.//td[6]/text()').get(),
                'Rate':tr.xpath('.//td[7]/text()').get()
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

To search for an XPATH within an element, you need to put a dot in front of xpath expression, like below:

```
tr.xpath(".//tbody//tr[position()>2 and position()<23]")
```

Did not test it, but this is the correct way. Scrapy documentation: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/

Comment: Still the array is empty sadly

Comment: response is empty array